# new range with electrical specs of 50 amps but my electrical panel breaker 40 amps and I'm not sure if i have a 50-amp plug is this safe?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, range

Installing a new range with 50-amp requirements but the electrical panel has a 40-amp breaker.
is it safe? this range is a gift and i am in process of getting the exact model number and specs thanks for the feedback,
Range will be a Bertazzoni PRO304insxt which one website says it's 50amp range and one says it's a 40-amp range. When I get it, I'll know more and if needed I'll hire an electrician.
I called Bertazzoni and they confirmed that 40-amp breaker was sufficient. however, I have a new question about the plug. My old range has a 3-prong plug, but the Bertazzoni has a 4-prong plug. Bertazzoni said i could use a 3 prong i just had to connect the ground to neutral but couldn't recommend one or I could get an electrician to change the outlet to a 4 prong plug. Could someone recommend a 50amp 3 prong plug to install into the PRO304insxt.

Comment: Does the range require 50 amps or merely have a 50 amp plug?  It is allowable to have a 40 amp breaker on a 50 amp outlet for reasons that can get complicated quickly.  Perhaps a short explanation on that is the circuit would be for a singular device and it would be on the installer to check if a 40 amp breaker is appropriate before use.  Please find the electrical requirements for the range and report back on required ampere rating for the circuit.

Comment: How many kW is the range rated to pull?

Comment: Do you have the option to take the range back and get a range compatible with your 40A electrical setup?

Comment: Did this question have to be closed so soon?  Does any question need to be closed before it has 12 hours for people to find the question and consider viable answers to give?  I suspect there's better means to raise my concerns but I'm still trying to figure out how this web forum works.

Comment: @MacGuffin Unfortunately, "closed" is a really, really, really bad term for what goes on here, but we're stuck with it because that's how StackExchange works, not just this piece (DIY) of StackExchange. To me (and many others), "closed" sounds just like "deleted". But in reality it is more like "on hold". Specifically in this case **needs details or clarity**. As in, model # would help a lot (to determine true requirements of the new range) and pictures or other details showing the existing wiring. Model #s - whether ranges or heat pumps - are key to giving proper, complete, accurate answers.

Comment: The answer given below is something I believe quite helpful, and it was done without knowing a specific model number, range wattage, or so many other details.  Had the question been closed to answers earlier then we'd not get even that.  With the question closed to new answers it is difficult for anyone to provide helpful answers like it, and I suspect there's a handful of people that would be willing to give great answers if this was still open.  Can we at least give some leeway to new contributors before closing questions based on "lack of clarity"?

Comment: @MacGuffin I agree that sometimes people are a bit quick to jump to "Close". But the reasoning is sound - an answer (beyond the relatively general answer I provided) really needs more specifics about the particular equipment and/or existing wiring. That's just the way it is. Look at the top line of my answer "**we don't know for sure**". If you call up a doctor and say "I've got a fever and other symptoms, do I have COVID?" the answer will be (or at least, *should* be) "Maybe, but it could be the flu or it could be something else *and we need more details to figure it out*." The difference

Comment: is that there "closed" takes the form of "I can't help you right now. Provide me with more information or come to my office to be evaluated" where here "closed" takes the form of "Give us more details". And yes, some people (but we tend to discourage that here because an awful lot *can* be truly DIY) answer a question like this with "call an electrician".

Comment: _Some_ questions get closed, @MacGuffin because when we ask for more details, _years_ go by without getting them. Sometimes, closing them quickly is just short cutting all that waiting. Unfortunately, it happens _far_ too often that we ask for more details and never get them. Also, as of this writing, the question is 14 hours old and it was closed at ~12 hours, so even by your suggested standard...

Comment: In this particular instance, it appears that the OP is responsive and will get us more info. When that happens, the question will (most likely) be reopened - I'd certainly vote for if the details are there to do so. Just so you know, there have only ever been 1888 questions that even came up for reopening votes on a site with nearly 79k questions - sadly, it's rare that we get the info we ask for...

Comment: I believe that there's enough clarity to re-open.  With the range being either 40 or 50 amp the plug, if any, is going to be of a 50 amp configuration.  If no plug is attached then it will be hardwired or have a 50 amp plug attached during installation.

Comment: Actually recently have been inclined to close more questions, in order to stop new SE contributors mining through  5 year old open questions and posting new repetitive answers.

Answer (score 6):

The plot thickens...

Based on the make/model # Bertazzoni PRO304insxt, the [specifications page](https://us.bertazzoni.com/downloads/6885/3257/PROF304INSXT%20Specifications%20Sheet.pdf?act=download) says:

> Electrical supply
>
> 120/240V 60 Hz – 13000W
>
> 120/208V 60Hz – 11700W
>
> 40 Amp dedicated circuit
>
> Power connection NEMA 14-50P plug with 59" cord

We'll ignore the 208V part, as that is likely not relevant and doesn't change much anyway.

So that leaves 3 pieces:

> 120/240V 60 Hz – 13000W

which should mean 13000W/240V = 54A

> 40 Amp dedicated circuit

which should mean 40A peak, 32A continuous. And both of those numbers are way below 54A.

> Power connection NEMA 14-50P plug with 59" cord

which is standard for a 40A or a 50A plug-in range circuit.

So then we go to the [Installation Manual](https://us.bertazzoni.com/downloads/6885/3315/3100295_formato%20A3.pdf?act=download), page 9:

> The appliance shall be connected to a single phase electric line rated at 120/208Vac or 120/240Vac and 60Hz frequency.
>
> INSTALLATION REQUIREMENTS ELECTRICAL CONNECTION
>
> Type Voltage Circuit rating Electrical supply
>
> 30” INDDFM 120/208V 10300W 46A 40A
>
> 120/240V 11000W 48A 40A
>
> 30” INDDFS 120/208V 11700W 53A 40A
>
> 120/240V 13000W 56A 40A
>
> 36” INDDFM 120/208V 14000W 62A 40A
>
> 120/240V 14800W 64A 40A
>
> 36” INDDFS 120/208V 15600W 70,5A 50A
>
> 120/240V 17000W 73,5A 50A

which I **think** means:

For all the 30" (including yours) and the smaller of the 36" ranges, **even though the possible total power requirements are well above 40A, only a 40A circuit is required.** Similarly, for the largest 36" range, with total possible power requirements of 73.5A, only a 50A circuit is required.

If all that is true, the rationale is something like: Only if you turn on everything on "high" at the same time will you go significantly over 40A (or 50A). Since most of the time most people, except possibly for a few minutes at a time, will have some burners on high and some low, bake but not broil, etc., everything kind of works out OK.

**It may be worth a call/email to the manufacturer to verify.**

And if this is true, then if you have a proper 40A circuit already then you are all set.

###### Original answer, still applicable for a true 50A range:

In order to properly connect a 50A range, you need 4 things to all be rated 50A (or better):

- 50A breaker (should be exactly 50A, not more or less). In *most* cases, this is easy to swap, provided your panel is not really, really old or certain known problem types.
- Wire from breaker to junction box. This is *usually* the big problem. See [this chart](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/) for the details. Keep in mind that wire AWG is backwards - smaller numbers = larger capacity:

  - 6 AWG (or larger) NM-B cable (a.k.a., "Romex")
  - 8 AWG (or larger) copper wires in conduit
  - 6 AWG (or larger) aluminum wires in conduit

The wire is most often the problem because you can't just swap it like a breaker, and larger wire costs more so an older (e.g., 40A, which is typical) installation will usually only have the wire needed and not any larger. If your cable or wires are too small then replacement could be anything from an hour of work (if your kitchen is above an unfinished basement with the electrical panel, or if you have a subpanel in your kitchen) to many hours of work (running wire across a house, possibly having to patch holes in drywall afterwards...).

- 50A receptacle. This should be a [NEMA 14-50](https://amzn.to/3P4qvUY), assuming your range needs a neutral:

[image: 14-50]

- 50A plug/cord, also 14-50.

Note that the receptacle and plug/cord should be UL or ETL listed for safety. You *may* be able to use a hardwired connection instead of plug/cord/receptacle, but that depends on the instructions with your range.

##### There is no 14-40...

There is no 14-40 receptacle type. As a result, a 40A circuit (40A breaker, 40A rated wire or cable, appliance that uses up to 32A continuous) can *legitimately* have a 14-50 receptacle. So you **must** check the wires before swapping the 40A breaker for a 50A breaker to avoid a serious fire hazard (and code violation).